# Algorithm needed to calculate difference between two times

Tags: algorithm, datetime, time

I have an hour selection drop down `0-23` and minutes selection drop down `0-59` for `Start time` and `End time` respectively (so four controls).

I'm looking for an algorithm to calculate time difference using these four values.

Since they're not stored in fancy date/time selection controls, I don't think I can use any standard date/time manipulation functions.

How do I calculate the difference between the two times?

Comment: "so no language or script can be used" - what?

Comment: Seems like it would be back to pen and paper then... X-)

Comment: How does one implement an algorithm without a "language or script"

Comment: Guys, Can't use language or script because my old fellow developer designed a form with an hour and minutes drop down for two time selector. It's just a combo box , no date picker. So, I don't have any option to use date functions. That's why need algorithm , I know it's headache :-)

@Bryon, Like in old days we used to write code for find odd or even nos or generate Fibonacci series or prime numbers :)

Comment: So you mean you just can't use date functions, yes? Presumably comparison, multiplication and subtraction are okay? :-)

Comment: Sense. This question makes none.

Comment: @Rishi, I've cleaned it up a bit based on what you've said in your comments. Please confirm that the intent of the question hasn't been changed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This pseudo-code gives you the algorithm to work out the difference in minutes. It assumes that, if the start time is after the end time, the start time was actually on the previous day.

```
const MINS_PER_HR = 60, MINS_PER_DAY = 1440

startx = starthour * MINS_PER_HR + startminute
endx = endhour * MINS_PER_HR + endminute

duration = endx - startx
if duration < 0:
    duration = duration + MINS_PER_DAY
```

The `startx` and `endx` values are the number of minutes since midnight.

This is basically doing:

- Get number of minutes from start of day for start time.
- Get number of minutes from start of day for end time.
- Subtract the former from the latter.
- If result is negative, add number of minutes in a day.

---

Don't be so sure though that you can't use date/time manipulation functions. You may find that you could easily construct a date/time and calculate differences with something like:

```
DateTime startx = new DateTime (1, 1, 2010, starthour, startminute, 0);
DateTime endx   = new DateTime (1, 1, 2010, endhour  , endminute  , 0);
Integer duration = DateTime.DiffSecs(endx, startx) / 60;
if (duration < 0)
    duration = duration + 1440;
```

although it's probably not needed for your simple scenario. I'd stick with the pseudo-code I gave above unless you find yourself doing some trickier date/time manipulation.

---

If you then want to turn the duration (in minutes) into hours and minutes:

```
durHours = int(duration / 60)
durMinutes = duration % 60 // could also use duration - (durHours * 60)
```

Comment: Thanks Pax, 

T1=5: 50 
T2=8:30

startx= 5*60 + 50 = 350 
endx=8*60+30 = 510 

duration = 510- 350 = 160 = 2 hr 40 mins correct should be 2 hr 50 mins

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Yes, some mathematical ability in the sexagesimal system :-) From 5:50 to 8:30 in two hours and _forty_ minutes. Two hours takes you from 5:50 to 7:50, ten minutes to 8:00 then thirty minutes to 8:30. The ten and the thirty make forty minutes, not fifty. I'm not sure where this insistence is coming from that it's 2:50 duration. Is there something _we're_ missing?

Comment: paxdiablo,

No you are not missing anything. Still I'm thinking why did I put 50.. Something went wrong to my mathematical intellect..

Answer (score 1):

This will compute duration in minutes including the year as factor

```
//* Assumptions:
Date is in Julian Format

startx = starthour * 60 + startminute
endx = endhour * 60 + endminute
duration = endx - startx
if duration <= 0:
    duration = duration + 1440
end-if
if currday > prevday
    duration = duration + ((currday-preday) - 1 * 1440)
end-if
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check to see if the end time is greater than or equal to the start time to prevent any problems. To do this you first check to see if the End_Time_Hour is greater than Start_Time_Hour. If they're equal you would instead check to see if End_Time_Min is greater than or equal to Start_Time_Min. 
Next you would subtract Start_Time_Hour from End_Time_Hour. Then you would subtract Start_Time_Min from End_Time_Min. If the difference of the minutes is less than 0 you would decrement the hour difference by one and add the minute difference to 60 (or 59, test that). Concat these two together and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks Aaron .Can you confirm I'm demonstrating correctly ,


T1= 5:50
T2=8:30

h=  8 - 5 = 3

m=30-50 = -20 

since m is less than 0 so , 

h= 3-1 = 2 

now add the minute difference to 60 , 

m = 60+20 = 80 

result , 2:80 ?

Comment: I meant add the minutes difference but leaving the negative sign. So 30-50 = -20... m = 60 + -20 = 40. Or you could just subtract the absolute value :D

Comment: Aaron, Thanks.. but it will still come 2:40 , but correct one should be 2:50 :P

Comment: Why the hell I've written 50 instead of 40 :( ..Sorry Aaron something came into my mind and such type mismatch happened..

Comment: Cool, well did this help you out then?

Comment: Aaron, There is one more scenario which I'm thinking.. Let's say Start time is 23:59 and end time is 1:30 ..

Comment: Hmmm...well I guess the constraint that the start time is before the end time doesn't apply then? I figured so since there's no date field. Anyways, to do this just check to see if the end time is greater than the start time. If so you could add 24 to the end time's hour and proceed as normal. Example given:
Hour_Diff = (End_Hour + 24) - Start_Hour = (1 + 24) - 23 = 25 - 23 = 2
Min_Diff = End_Min - Start_Min = 30 - 59 = -29... < 0 so add 60 to min and decrement Hour_Diff...Min_Diff = -29 + 60 = 31 and Hour_Diff = 1
Concat to get 1:31 for total difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_time_hr = 5;

$start_time_mi = 50;

$end_time_hr = 8;

$end_time_mi = 30;

$diff = (($end_time_hr*60)+$end_time_mi) - (($start_time_hr*60)+$start_time_mi);

$diff_hr = (int)($diff / 60);

$diff_mi = (int)($diff) - ($diff_hr*60);

echo $diff_hr . ':' . $diff_mi;
```

Answer (score 0):

simple equation should help:

```
mindiff = 60 + endtime.min - starttime.min
hrdiff  = ((mindiff/60) - 1) + endtime.hr - starttime.hr
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the duration in hours and minutes

```
h1 = "hora1"
m1 "min1"
h2 "hora2"
m2 = "min2"

if ( m1 > m2)
{
    h3 = (h2 - h1) - 1;
}
else
{
    h3 = h2 - h1;
}

m1 = 60 - m1;

if (m1 + m2 >= 60)
{
    m3 = 60 - (m1 + m2);

} else if (m3 < 0)
{
    m3 = m3 * -1;
}
else
{
    m3 = m1 + m2;
}

System.out.println("duration:" + h3 + "h" + m3 + "min");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function that returns the number of days since some start date (e.g. dayssince1900) you can just convert both dates to seconds since that start date, do the ABS(d1-d2) then convert the seconds back to whatever format you want e.g. HHHH:MM:SS

Simple e.g.

```
SecondsSince1900(d)
{
return  dayssince1900(d)*86400
       +hours(d)*3600
       +minutes(d)*60
       +seconds(d);
}

diff = ABS(SecondsSince1900(d1)-SecondsSince1900(d2))

return format(diff DIV 3600)+':'+format((diff DIV 60) MOD 60)+':'+format(diff MOD 60);
```

Hum: Not that simple if you have to take into account the leap seconds astronomers are keen to put in from time to time.