# Difference between two times python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I can't get this working. I'm tired of searching, but I can't find anything.
I don't have a date, I only have time (01:45, 05:30).

I'm only using the library 'Time', currently I have the code above, which gives me the minutes between the hours. But this is not enough.

In this example, the final result should be:

225 minutes

3 hours (rounded down)

```
hour_beg = '01:45'
hour_close = '05:30'

hours_begin = int(hour_beg.split(':')[0]) # 01
minutes_begin = int(hour_beg.split(':')[1]) # 45
hours_end = int(hour_close.split(':')[0]) # 05
minutes_end = int(hour_close.split(':')[1]) # 30

total_minutes = abs((hours_begin - hours_end ) * 60)
```

How can I accomplished that?

Comment: ... all assuming the timestamps belong to the same day? That is, what if you've got '23:00' to '01:00'?

Comment: Won't be a problem, I can verify if the begin time is lower than the end time. But it's a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `(hours_end - hours_begin) * 60 + minutes_end - minutes_begin`.

Comment: Hello (first thanks), I got to the same result few moments from posting this topic in this url: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518819/algorithm-needed-to-calculate-difference-between-two-times)

My problem is now on round values. I have a program which gives, in hours -> ~3,45 -> minutes -> 225

I tried: `hours_result = round(abs(hours_begin - hours_end), 2)` but it's giving me: hours -> 4,00 -> minutes -> 225.

How can I reach that "3,45"?

Comment: why are you still using `hours_begin - hours_end` instead of the above expression?

Comment: Because I need to get the minutes and the hours.
`minutes_total = (hours_end - hours_begin) * 60 + minutes_end - minutes_begin`
`hours_result = round(abs(hours_begin - hours_end), 2)`

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry but just giving you an answer isn't going to help you if you can't think or **won't think**. You can get the total hours, with the fraction included, from the same expression.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> time1 = parser.parse("01:45")
>>> time2 = parser.parse("05:30")
>>> print (time2-time1).seconds
13500
>>> print (time2-time1).seconds/60
225
```

Answer (score 2):

Use datetime to get a timedelta.

```
import datetime
hour_beg = '01:45'
hour_close = '05:30'

first = datetime.datetime.strptime(hour_beg, '%H:%M')
second = datetime.datetime.strptime(hour_close, '%H:%M')
delta = first - second
```

Comment: You probably need `datetime.datetime.strptime(hour_beg, '%H:%M')`