# How do I properly compute and convert the starting time and ending time of the call in minutes?

Tags: c, math

The start and end time are based on a 24 hour clock format. The task is that we will input the start and the end time then we will compute the length of the call and convert the result in minutes.

Sample output:
Start time: 1810
End time: 2000
Length of call: 110 minutes

Here's what I did try doing. First, I tried to minus the start and end time and automatically turn the answer into positive. Now if the total result(resultMain) is greater than 120, it will multiply the result to (.60). Else if the result is greater than 60 and less than 120, then it will just get minus 40 instead of it getting multiplied by (.60). My problem is that my result is inconsistent, sometimes the answer is correct but sometimes it is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int startTime, endTime, result1, result2;
    double totalTime1, totalTime2, resultMain;
    
    printf("\nPLDT Telephone Call Charge\n");
    printf("\nStart time\t: ");
    scanf("%d", &startTime);
    printf("End time\t: ");
    scanf("%d", &endTime);

    totalTime1 = startTime - endTime;
    resultMain = fabs(totalTime1);
    
    if(resultMain >= 120){
        
    totalTime2 = resultMain * .60;
    result1 = ceil(totalTime2); 
    result2 = fabs(result1);
    
    printf("Length of call\t: %d minutes\n", result2);
    }else if(resultMain >= 60 && resultMain < 120){

        totalTime2 = resultMain - 40;
        result1 = ceil(totalTime2);
        result2 = fabs(result1);

        printf("Length of call\t: %d minutes\n", result2);
    }else{
        totalTime2 = resultMain;
        result1 = ceil(totalTime2);
        result2 = fabs(result1);
        
        printf("Length of call\t: %d minutes\n", result2);
    }
   return 0;
    }
```

Example of correct answer:
Start time: 0123
End time: 0224
Length of call: 61 minutes

Example of wrong answer:
Start time: 0852
End time: 0906
Length of call: 54 minutes

Example of wrong answer:
Start time: 0805
End time: 1210
Length of call: 243 minutes

Comment: Your input is integers, your output is integers. There's no need for any floating point arithmetic or functions here.

Comment: Where do you convert time inputs to raw epoch minutes?

Comment: Also, to get the difference between the start and end times, reverse the subtraction: `endTime - startTime`.

Comment: But to do proper calculations, you really need to separate hours and minutes from the input. Like for example `startHours = startTime / 100; startMinutes = startTime % 100;`.  Then work with the hours and minutes separately.

Comment: Once separated hours and minutes you'd calculate analogously to how you learnt decimal subtraction with overflow at school: If minutes difference is negative, add 60 to it and subtract additionally one (the carry!) from the hours difference. Final result will be hours difference multiplied by 60 plus the minutes difference.

Comment: One way is to get milliseconds for both as consistent units, do the subtraction, and convert to hours, minutes, and seconds.  Another would be to use Java Duration class as it was intended.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

Comment: @duffymo Why millisconds if smallest unit is minutes anyway? Consistently as minutes would do the trick just as fine already. And Java link is not suitable for C problem... Conversion in C (for QA): `xTime = xTime % 100 + xTime / 100 * 60;`

Comment: Why?  Because you just need a common unit between the two values you're subtracting.  Pick fortnights if you wish.  It only matters that they are common between the two values.

Comment: @duffymo Using fortnight is [too weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortnight) a unit. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this algorithm to calculate the difference in minutes between two times:

```
const MINS_PER_HR = 60, MINS_PER_DAY = 1440

startx = starthour * MINS_PER_HR + startminute
endx = endhour * MINS_PER_HR + endminute

duration = endx - startx
if duration < 0:
    duration = duration + MINS_PER_DAY
```

See: [Algorithm needed to calculate difference between two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518819/algorithm-needed-to-calculate-difference-between-two-times)

This code will implement it for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int startTime, endTime, startHour, startMin, endHour, endMin, duration;
    
    printf("\nPLDT Telephone Call Charge\n");
    printf("\nStart time\t: ");
    scanf("%04d", &startTime);
    printf("End time\t: ");
    scanf("%04d", &endTime);

    startHour = startTime / 100;
    startMin  = startTime % 100;
    endHour   = endTime / 100;
    endMin    = endTime % 100;
    duration  = (endHour * 60 + endMin) - (startHour * 60 + startMin);
    if (duration < 0)
        duration += 60 * 24;
    printf("Length of call\t: %d minutes\n", duration);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: Link added for algorithm explanation. No need to duplicate it here.

Comment: @AnthonyKelly *No need to duplicate it here.* Wrong.  [Links go bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: Pseudocode is only a little better; it is not a real explanation, and the pseudocode currently in the answer does not cover how to separate the time into hours and minutes. Think about the problem to be solved here. The problem to be solved here is not calculating the difference between two times. The problem to be solved here is explaining how to calculate the difference between two times. OP read the hours and minutes as a single decimal numeral, then tried subtracting two such numbers and also multiplying by .60. This shows they have some wrong concepts about manipulating times…

Comment: … and that means an answer needs to clarify these concepts. So one concept to be cleared up is about handling a time entered as three or four decimal digits. Either you read it character-by-character and parse it into a numeral for the hours and a numeral for the minutes or you can read it as one numeral and then separate it. (And a detail answered could go into pitfalls, such as what happens if the user enters “370”.)…

Comment: … Another concept to be cleared up is how to do arithmetic on hours and minutes. It can either be done with custom operations to work on the hours and minutes separately, with carrying/borrowing as appropriate, or by converting from an hours-and-minutes representation to a minutes representation and then doing ordinary arithmetic. Just saying “Here is an algorithm” does not solve the problem of correcting mistaken concepts, so it is not a great answer.

Comment: Adding to what has been said so far: Providing complete ready-to-use code (and worse if not commented) always brings the risk of just getting copied without further thinking about, resulting in the QA not learning anything from...

Comment: The `0` in `"%04d"` serves no purpose.  `"%4d"` is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

**No need for any floating point math**

**Before subtracting, break time into hours and minutes**

```
int startTime_hours = startTime/100;
int startTime_mins = startTime%100;
startTime_mins += startTime_hours*60; // startTime_mins is now the total minutes.
```

**The difference is the end minus the start**

```
int diff = endTime_mins - startTime_mins;
```

**When difference is negative, add a day worth of time**

Example: start time just before midnight and the end time after midnight.

```
if (diff < 0) {
  diff += 24*60;
}
```

**Only 1 case needed for printing**

```
printf("Length of call\t: %d minutes\n", diff);
```